# JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "be"

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I ejected my CRNA app, I compiled it and run it on my android device. Then I got this error while  trying to do a search of a movie in the app which is managed by code below. Any solution?

```
const API_TOKEN = "********************************";
export function getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText(text, page){
const url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=' + API_TOKEN 
 + '&language=fr&query=' + text + "&page=" + page
 return fetch(url)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .catch((error) => console.error(error))

}

export function getImageFromApi(name){
return 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300' + name
}

export function getFilmDetailFromApi(id){
return fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '?api_key=' + 
API_TOKEN + '&language=fr')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it's not giving you proper JSON

Comment: it worked with expo before i ejected the app though :(

Comment: Was it the code that didn't have any errors?

Comment: @hongdevelop yes the code didn't have error before (when i was using expo)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
this.state = {
    ...
    responseDATA = '',  //You can also use an array
}

export function getFilmDetailFromApi(id){
    return fetch('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '?api_key=' + API_TOKEN + '&language=fr')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.state.responseDATA = responseJson.movie  //here movie is path of the data that you want from the JSON recieved
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is already addressed in another function  as follows:  ... `this.setState({
            films: [  ...responseJson.results ]
          })` ... calling getFilmDetailFromApi()

Comment: i tried that, and it didn't work. seems that it wasn't a problem in the code but a url problem. i tried the solution of @jeremy and it worked. but then I put the original url i used and it worked too. So in the first place all was right.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem, but in the end

i find it

"api is down"

you can check with your api key

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=3d99a0336ddf835ade204ef86d5993dd&language=fr&query=me

[api is down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4FnL.png)

Comment: actually i seemed to me that the link is not dead, when i open in the browser, i do get the data displayed, but on the app, it gives the error. The solution of @Jeremy worked (y).

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem and I just found the solution.

The problem is TheMovieDB, if you try to just run the url in your browser you'll see "be right back"

But in the URL, you just need to change the "3" to a "4" and it work ! (I can't explain why but it works !)

> https://api.themoviedb.org/**4**/search/movie?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&language=fr&query=super

;)

Comment: thanks @jeremy . i changed 3 into 4 and it worked . the fix is weird though (changing 3 to 4 in the url). but then again, i put back 3 and now it works too. seems like there was a failure in the link at the database side or something like that.